# Java: speed of searching in a Map and for circle

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a list of module which has two fields: time and size and I need to find one module according to given time/size.

I have two solutions:

1. for(Module module: myModuleList)
2. I create a Map and use Map.get().

and I wonder which would be faster or consume less ressources? because this manipulation would be raise periodically with a more and more large module list.

Comment: Iterating would be O(n); HashMap get() is O(1).  Go for the HashMap.

Comment: You could also implement equals and hashCode, and search for a module using indexOf.

Comment: @duffymo - What about time taken for creation of hashmap?. I agree this will be a one time thing BTW so all future reads are `O(1)`

Comment: None of this is likely to matter.  It'll be a micro-optimization at best.  If the size becomes that much of a problem, I'd suggest putting it in a database.  In any case the best thing to do is profile, get some real data, and fix only if you have a problem.

Comment: @duffymo asymptotic runtime complexity is not a micro optimization. Also, I would generally agree to use a HashMap for, say, a server-side application where you can use as much memory as you like. On a memory constrained client, though, the decision might be otherwise.

Comment: What are the dynamics of your module lis? I.e. how does it get populated? Does it start empty and gets populated during the run time of the program? Do you always build a complete list before each search? How big does it get? Are there only additions or removal as well? Need some context to give a useful answer.

Comment: @Vlad you are right, i missed some infos. I create an empty list and populate it at runtime. I check the list periodically and treate them, but just modify a field of the selected module. and I dont remove module, only add. The list would be perhaps 80 or 100 , but not too bigger than 100.

Comment: I doubt that this will matter.  Anything will do.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan - You cannot judge whether this is a micro optimization without knowing a lot more about the rest of his app and use cases.  Like I said in my first comment: an O(1) get method will work fine.  Anything other thought requires profiling data.

Comment: @bugger can there potentially be multiple modules with the same time and size values? If time&size pairs are not unqiue (it would be strange to assume so based on the field names alone) then they can't be used as a key and HashMap approach eaither won't work or won't give any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the list is `O(myModuleList.size())` whereas using `Map.get()` is `O(1)` for a `HashMap` or `O(log(myModuleList.size()))` for a `TreeMap`. So, if you are optimizing for performance, then using a `HashMap` would be the best solution. In almost all cases, you should reach for a `HashMap` by default unless you also need to iterate over the elements in key order, in which case it would make sense to use a `TreeMap`. So, the short answer is that you should use a HashMap.

For a very large number of elements (which is not the case that you are describing), it's possible to improve the space usage of the HashMap (albeit at the expense of speed) by tuning the load factor and initial capacity (though you will not need to do this in ordinary usages). There are also alternative map datastructures that give different tradeoffs in performance and space, depending on your needs.

Comment: I don't see how a TreeMap will be any more memory efficient than a HashMap.

Comment: @duffymo, HashMap is an open addressing implementation. To maintain performance, the map maintains a large amount of excess capacity compared to the tree implementation. A tree map needs 4n space (key, value, left, right) whereas a hash map requires a variable amount of space depending on the load factor. For Java, it defaults to 0.75, meaning that it takes 4N where N = 2n (key, value) when it is saturated to capacity. When it is not saturated, the space is even less economical. Yes, they are both O(n), but the leading order coefficient is significant in practice.

Comment: In practice for 100 elements?  Let's see some data on this.

Comment: That's still 400 vs 800 pointers (3.2kb vs 6.4kb assuming 64-bit pointers). The OP also hasn't specified the size. On a server or desktop where RAM is highly available, you're right that HashMap is the better default choice, but on a memory-constrained phone, for example,  that difference of 3.2kb might matter.

Comment: Please.  3.2kb?  Not these days; not even on my 5 year old phone.  The OP did specify 100 or so entries.  Not significant until the data suggests so.  You're nano-optimizing and more worried about your ego than a good answer now.

Comment: Oh. The 100 was mentioned in the comments, not the original question. You're right. I missed that.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan This discussion is totally irrelevant to the original question but HashMap does not use open addressing. It uses separate chaining + linkedlists until Java 7, and separate chaining with b-trees since Java 8. If you don't remove elements, a HashMap always takes less memory than a TreeMap: 8*x (overhead TreeEntry vs Node) << ((2^(log(x)/log(2))-x) * 4 (overhead of unused space in tab[]). Remains pathological use cases like a formerly large collection were almost all the elements have been removed, since the array of a HashMap is never shrinked...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @ClémentMATHIEU. Years ago in college I was told that HashMap<> uses open addressing, but that probably hasn't been true for a long time. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU if you don't mind my asking, can you expound on your calculation? I'm finding myself still doubtful and realized that I don't fully understand how you came to that result.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Let's use jol to see the real cost of each elements. Code is here: https://gist.github.com/cykl/48c501f95ad618fd3217. TreeMap$Entry costs 8 bytes more that a HashMap$Node, but 4 bytes of HashMap.tab are also used. A TreeMap cost 4 * x more bytes than a HashMap. But the "tab" array in HashMap uses exponential growth, so its size is x rounded to the next power of two. The number of empty slots is then 2^(log(x)/log(2)) - x and each slot cost 4 bytes. I assume no collision and omit the load factor since it has only a small impact.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that perhaps this was assuming that the HashMap was filled to capacity, so I adapted this Gist to investigate further: https://gist.github.com/michaelsafyan/b4d8aaa1820657e3f068           I have to say that I am quite surprised at how close the sizes are, even when no initial capacity is specified. (And you're right that the HashMap is indeed less memory consuming than TreeMap).